# aws cli describe-instances can't set brackets

Tags: aws-cli

I'm a new to aws-cli.
I want to get instances information from terminal, but I can't stop it with brackets instance name.

here is command,

```
 aws ec2 describe-instances --filters 'Name=tag:Name,Values=[hoge]*'
```

instance name like,

```
[hoge]instance-1
```

Can someone fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brackets are special characters and needs to be escaped; see the "*To add tags with special characters*" section on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-tags.html

Example:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters 'Name=tag:Name,Values="[hoge]*"'
```

By the way I would also have given myself a thought on altering my naming convention if I was using brackets in tag values; those characters work when tagging EC2 instances, but not necessarily when tagging instances of other AWS services; see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html#tag-restrictions