# AWS-CLI: How do I filter autoscalinggroups

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-auto-scaling

Unable to find example to use filters https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/describe-auto-scaling-groups.html#options

Comment: What do you want to filter for?

Comment: Tag: eks:nodegroup-name, Value=cassandra

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```sh
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=xxx" "Name=tag:env,Values=dev"
```

[more](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1221)

UPDATE: I believe you need the `tag:` or `tag-key:` per the error message you provided, as in the example above: `The filter criteria isn't valid. Valid filter types for the Name attribute of filters are: tag-key, tag-value and tag:<key>`. The confusing part is that your tag has the `:` (COLON) character ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33349524/aws-cli-describe-instances-cant-set-brackets)), which either needs escaped or not used or replaced.

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --filters "Name=tag:\"eks:nodegroup-name\",Values=cassandra"
```

Comment: `aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --filters "Name=eks:nodegroup-name,Values=cassandra"

An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the DescribeAutoScalingGroups operation: The filter criteria isn't valid. Valid filter types for the Name attribute of filters are: tag-key, tag-value and tag:<key>`

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following command:

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query 'AutoScalingGroups[?contains(Tags[?Key==`eks:nodegroup-name`].Value, `cassandra`)]' --region [AWS_REGION]
```

Or if you only want the ASG name you can filter it using:

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query 'AutoScalingGroups[?contains(Tags[?Key==`eks:nodegroup-name`].Value, `cassandra`)].[AutoScalingGroupName]' --region [AWS_REGION]
```

---

Reference:

[Filtering AWS CLI output](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html#cli-usage-filter-client-side)

Comment: Thanks @omar after reading further I was able to use filter option too, `aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --filters "Name=tag:eks:nodegroup-name,Values=cassandra"`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same without double quotes with the filters, and it worked.

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --filters Name=tag:\eks:nodegroup-name\,Values=cassandra
```